# tmux split into 4 panes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux

I am using tmux 2.1.
I have googled this and it seems I can split a window into multiple panes by using the following command:

```
tmux new-session \; split-window \; split-window -h \; split-window -v
```

(not sure why the \; is needed but it only works with it)

My issue is the the layout I want is the following:

[image]

The only way I can achieve this is by creating 3 windows horizontaly and then going back to the middle window and then splitting that window and I can only do this manually.

Is there anyway to do this via a command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Briefly, this sequence is what you want:

```
tmux new-window \; split-window -p 66 \; split-window -d \; split-window -h
```

The flow is:

1. `tmux new-window`: create a window (ok, you wanted a *new-session*, that does create a *window* upon startup)
2. `split-window -p 66`: allocate bottom two thirds of the vertical space to a secondary pane and focus it
3. `split-window -d`: split bottom pane in half, vertically, *without* focusing the new pane (i.e. focus stays on second – now *center* – pane)
4. `split-window -h`: split center pane in half, horizontally

As for *why the \; is needed*, check [tmux man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1):

> Multiple commands may be specified together as part of a command
>   sequence.  Each command should be separated by spaces and a semicolon;
>   commands are executed sequentially from left to right and lines ending
>   with a backslash continue on to the next line, except when escaped by
>   another backslash.  A literal semicolon may be included by escaping it
>   with a backslash (for example, when specifying a command sequence to
>   bind-key).

Comment: Thanks for this. I only got your command to work if I used tmux new-session. tmux new-window did nothing. Thanks also for taking the time to explain the \; thing :)

Comment: A quick note: It seems your command will work on already existing tmux session. (sorry still new to tmux) I sometimes use a few terminals with different tmux sessions as I am working on different projects and I need different displays for them.

Comment: How do you add a 5th 20% width of the screen pane to the left of the whole area?

Comment: @rubo77: `tmux split-window -f -h -p 20 -t :.1 -b`